# Derivative of a vector function with respect to a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

I have a vector function: $f(r)=[f_{x}(r), f_{y}(r), f_{z}(r)]$, where $ r=[x, y, z]. $

How to calculate the derrivative: $ \frac{d f(r)}{d r}$ ?

Will it be a matrix m of elements $ m_{ij}=\frac{\partial f_{i}(r)}{\partial j} $?

Does it have something to do with the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: It's not a notation I personally like... the few places where I have seen it, they write $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ meaning precisely the Jacobian of $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: How to interpret such a derivative is a matter of convention. As far as I'm aware, the typical interpretation is a matrix: $$\left(\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\vec x}\right)_{ij}=\frac{\partial\vec f_i}{\partial\vec x_j}$$ See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) for some discussion.

Comment: What about the directional derivative? Maybe it would be a better interpretation?